# How to make push notification with GCM work on android?

Tags: java, android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using as backend Google app Engine.
I activated my project for GCM from Google API and I have my API key.
I managed to register each user, in my database each user has a regid that is sent from android app to my server. This ID is generate by gcm.

Now What ? I try to send notification to all my regid users however no notification seem to appear.

Shall I create a notification myself in my android app ? If yes how and where ?

Also this is the java code on my backend: Is this correct or shall I use something specific with gcm ?

```
` List regIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        regIds.add("APA91bG_pKoxxxxxxxx......");
        regIds.add("APA91bF_uxoo0-xxxxxx....");`

`// If you want the SDK to automatically retry a certain number of times, use the
// standard send method.
        Sender sender = new Sender("AIzaSyAgxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .addData("message", "Hello")
                .addData("location", "000 111 33")
                .build();
        try {
            MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, regIds, 5);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            temp.setData(e.toString());
        }
        return temp ;
`
```

[image]
In other words how to make step 5 and 6 ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with any push-notification on Android app you should implement own BroadcastReceiver to receive and Intent Service to handle incoming messages. and update manifests. I'd recommend you to read carefully about it [here](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html).